# Cleanest way to perform pandas join involving an index and also columns

Tags: python, join, pandas, concatenation

Suppose I want to merge (concat?) two pandas tables by joining on both an unnamed index and a column (here "identifier"). Is there a clean way to do this?

```
                               tvType         identifier 
2014-04-08 12:05:00  TMM_ISPREAD  ISIN: US92344GAS57 
2014-04-08 12:10:00  TMM_ISPREAD  ISIN: US92344GAS57 
2014-04-08 12:15:00  TMM_ISPREAD  ISIN: US92344GAS57 
2014-04-08 12:20:00  TMM_ISPREAD  ISIN: US92344GAS57 
2014-04-08 12:20:00  OTHER        ISIN: US92344GAS75 
                                   tv         identifier 
2014-04-08 12:05:00  131.957086  ISIN:US92344GAS57 
2014-04-08 12:10:00  131.932117  ISIN:US92344GAS57 
2014-04-08 12:15:00  131.945260  ISIN:US92344GAS57 
2014-04-08 12:20:00  131.888946  ISIN:US92344GAS57 
2014-04-08 12:20:00  131.920969  ISIN:US92344GAS75
```

To be clear, what I'd like to get to is

```
                               tv         identifier       tvType
2014-04-08 12:05:00  131.957086  ISIN:US92344GAS57  TMM_ISPREAD
2014-04-08 12:10:00  131.932117  ISIN:US92344GAS57  TMM_ISPREAD
2014-04-08 12:15:00  131.945260  ISIN:US92344GAS57  TMM_ISPREAD
2014-04-08 12:20:00  131.888946  ISIN:US92344GAS57  TMM_ISPREAD
2014-04-08 12:20:00  131.920969  ISIN:US92344GAS75  OTHER
```

And my seemingly cumbersome way is

```
dfTv['time_index']     = dfTv.index
dfTvType['time_index'] = dfTvType.index
df = pd.merge( dfTv, dfTvType, on = ['identifier','time_index'] )
df = df.set_index(['time_index'])
```

(which names the index - not a side effect I really want)

Comment: a bad cut and paste!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply supply `left_index` and `right_index` too:

```
In [96]:

print df1
                          tvType         identifier
2014-04-08 12:05:00  TMM_ISPREAD  ISIN:US92344GAS57
2014-04-08 12:10:00  TMM_ISPREAD  ISIN:US92344GAS57
2014-04-08 12:15:00  TMM_ISPREAD  ISIN:US92344GAS57
2014-04-08 12:20:00  TMM_ISPREAD  ISIN:US92344GAS57
2014-04-08 12:25:00        OTHER  ISIN:US92344GAS75
In [97]:

print df2
                             tv         identifier
2014-04-08 12:05:00  131.957086  ISIN:US92344GAS57
2014-04-08 12:10:00  131.932117  ISIN:US92344GAS57
2014-04-08 12:15:00  131.945260  ISIN:US92344GAS57
2014-04-08 12:20:00  131.888946  ISIN:US92344GAS57
2014-04-08 12:25:00  131.920969  ISIN:US92344GAS75

In [98]:

print pd.merge(df2, df1, on = ['identifier'], left_index=True, right_index=True)
                             tv         identifier       tvType
2014-04-08 12:05:00  131.957086  ISIN:US92344GAS57  TMM_ISPREAD
2014-04-08 12:10:00  131.932117  ISIN:US92344GAS57  TMM_ISPREAD
2014-04-08 12:15:00  131.945260  ISIN:US92344GAS57  TMM_ISPREAD
2014-04-08 12:20:00  131.888946  ISIN:US92344GAS57  TMM_ISPREAD
2014-04-08 12:25:00  131.920969  ISIN:US92344GAS75        OTHER
```